# How to iterate a Firestore collection on Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection like this:
[image]

Take a look at **kost** collection. There are 4 docouments in it, and each document has the following fields: fasilitas, gender, harga, etc

For each document, I want to retrieve all the fields.

Now I have this:

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("kost").document();
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            for (DocumentSnapshot ds:task.getResult()){
                
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It's not even a correct code, `task.getResult()` is underlined:

> foreach not applicable to type
> 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

What's the correct way, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problems is in this code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("kost").document();
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
```

Your `docRef` points to a new, empty document. What you want instead is to point to the entire collection as shown in the documentation on [reading all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection):

```
db.collection("kost")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```